# SQLite: library routine called out of sequence - how to resolve this crash?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Okay, so my app is perfectly working on Android 2.3 and **crashes on 4.0.4.**

Im parsing an XML and **saving data to my SQLite database.**

This is not every time happens **but really often**, sometimes on button clicks sometimes on new Activity startups... etc

Crash Exception:

```
11-16 15:16:41.231: E/SQLiteQuery(6398): exception: library routine called out of sequence; query: SELECT _id, name, tipus, azonosito, gpsx, gpsy, pictures, telefonok, webcim, email, nyitvatartas, cim, orszag, befogadokepesseg, szolgaltatasok, arkategoria, leiras, ertekeles, pontszam, facebook, keywords, rating FROM shops_top20

11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KeySoft.OpenGuide/com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: library routine called out of sequence
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException: library routine called out of sequence
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.nativeFillWindow(Native Method)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:86)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:161)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:201)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.SqlShopsVissza(Top20.java:546)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.listakKirajzolasaEsValtas(Top20.java:165)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.onCreate(Top20.java:113)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
11-16 15:16:41.241: E/AndroidRuntime(6398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

**E D I T :
Ok, so i closed all the cursors just before i close all the db connections in my app, and NOW i got this excption:**

```
    11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KeySoft.OpenGuide/com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548): Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:165)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1250)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close(SQLiteDatabase.java:1220)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.close(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:265)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.DB_Adapter.close(DB_Adapter.java:273)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.SqlShopsVissza(Top20.java:558)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.listakKirajzolasaEsValtas(Top20.java:165)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Activities.Top20.onCreate(Top20.java:113)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
11-16 20:00:28.409: E/AndroidRuntime(7548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

**The problematic part in my code, is a function in my Top20 Activity, which is currently the following function:**

```
protected void getShopsFromSql(String whichTable){


            db.open();
            Cursor c;

            if(whichTable.equals("Top20")){
                c = db.getAllTop20Titles();
            }
            else if (whichTable.equals("Latest10")){
                c = db.getAllLatest10Titles();
            }
            else{
                c = db.getAllShopsFullTitles();
            }

                if (c.moveToFirst())  {
                    do  {

                        addShopToList(c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(4), c.getString(5), c.getString(12), c.getString(11), c.getString(3));
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }

                c.close(); 
                db.close(); //App Crashes here... why?
        }
```

db is my Database for sure, I Googled this error and of course it happens when i want to edit a value on a thread and iterate throu the same value by an other thread (background AsyncTask this time), but i have a singleton Database Adapter and i read here in stack that this kind of Database implementation is the best for Android apps.

I have an extended Application class with a single database and i call each and every time this database.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

 private static DB_Adapter globalDatabase;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        globalDatabase = new DB_Adapter(this);
    }

    public static DB_Adapter getDB() {

        return globalDatabase;
    }
```

}

Reference to the database in my apps like this:

```
public class Top20 extends Activity 
{


    private DB_Adapter db;
    private MyApp myApp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.top20);


        myApp = (MyApp) getApplication();

        db = myApp.getDB();

                    //...........morecode...etc..
```

SO:

My questions are:

Why is this error occured?
Am I doing right this singleton database implementation?

Thanks your advices,
Adam

Comment: I've seen this mostly caused by leaving connections/cursors open. Go through your code and make sure you explicitly `close()` all your cursors and databases when you're done using them.

Comment: Will check soon thanks for advice, i will edit soon.

Comment: Are you using getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() to instantiate your db object?  Did you put that code in a try/catch block as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be getting the `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're trying to close the database as some other thread is attempting to access it. Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm not sure what other threads you have accessing the DB, so hard to tell what else is going on.

As an aside, and possibly a better solution, is there a reason you're trying to close it? As Google FW engineer Dianne Hackborn says, you don't need to close the database since it will automatically be closed once your Process is killed. Refer to [link #1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/NwDRpHUXt0U/jIam4Q8-cqQJ) and [link #2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DAkbe6rzxXY) for multiple posts where she comments on this.